# Listview adding items and view header

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

Being new to winapi and usage of Listview I have trouble viewing column headers and subitems not visible within the listview i.e., the first column can be seen but subitems(column-1 and 2) are not displayed. Could readers let me know the right way of initializing items within a list view?

Column headers not being visible - I toggled the property setting "No Column Header" for the list control and it did not help with visualizing the column headers.

```
HWND listViewHandle = GetDlgItem(formHandle, IDC_CHART_LV);  // handle to the list control

//Add column definitions
LVCOLUMN lvc = { 0 };
lvc.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_FMT;
lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
//column 0
lvc.iSubItem = 0;
lvc.cx = 100;
lvc.pszText = TEXT("A");
ListView_InsertColumn(listViewHandle, 0, &lvc);
//column 1
lvc.iSubItem = 1;
lvc.cx = 200;
lvc.pszText = TEXT("B");
ListView_InsertColumn(listViewHandle, 1, &lvc);
//column 2
lvc.iSubItem = 2;
lvc.cx = 200;
lvc.pszText = TEXT("C");
ListView_InsertColumn(listViewHandle, 2, &lvc);

//Setup some dummy items within the listview
LV_ITEM lvItem = { 0 };

//Row 0
lvItem.iItem = 0;
ListView_InsertItem(listViewHandle, &lvItem);
ListView_SetItemText(listViewHandle, 0, 0, TEXT("RS"));
ListView_SetItemText(listViewHandle, 0, 1, TEXT("SS"));
ListView_SetItemText(listViewHandle, 0, 2, TEXT("VS"));

//Row 1
lvItem.iItem = 1;
ListView_InsertItem(listViewHandle, &lvItem);
ListView_SetItemText(listViewHandle, 1, 0, TEXT("SR"));
ListView_SetItemText(listViewHandle, 1, 1, TEXT("GS"));
ListView_SetItemText(listViewHandle, 1, 2, TEXT("SM"));

//Row 2
lvItem.iItem = 2;
ListView_InsertItem(listViewHandle, &lvItem);
ListView_SetItemText(listViewHandle, 2, 0, TEXT("GT"));
ListView_SetItemText(listViewHandle, 2, 1, TEXT("GS"));
ListView_SetItemText(listViewHandle, 2, 2, TEXT("SM"));

SendMessage(listViewHandle, LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
ListView_SetItemState(listViewHandle, 1, LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED);
```

Comment: Is your listview control style set to `LVS_REPORT` ?

Comment: @AndyBrown no the list is set to View "List"

Comment: @AndyBrown Setting View to LVS_REPORT did the trick. Thanks for the hint.